# How to populate records based on the string availability inside file in Linux

Tags: linux

i am not expert in Linux commands , seeking all your help for my requirement.

i have file  that has huge number of records, that we can be differentiated by three sections that is header record , Content and footer records .

File Sample Content :-

```
HDR1
HDR2
HDR3
LIN+1
bla blaa1 
Bla blaa2
......
.....
..
LIN+2
bla blaa1 
Bla blaa2
......
.....
..
Footer1
Footer2
Footer3
```

From the above sample records from a file , I want to populate the Lines from "LIN+2" to before "Footer1" line to another new file and delete the lines from the old file .

Please help with the command , your help will be much appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't give you the entire solution, but using these tips you can find out:

- In order to find an entry in a file, you can use `grep` (like `grep "LIN+2" filename)`.
- Once you have this, you can add `-n` to the result in order to know the line number of the result (like `grep -n "LIN+2" filename`).
- Using `awk`, you can make sure only to get that information (like `grep "LIN+2" filename | awk -F: '{print $1}'`).
- In order to see the first 10 lines of a file, do `head -n 10 filename`.
- In order to see the last 10 lines of a file, do `tail -n 10 filename`.

Using that information, you should be able to get your result.

Comment: Hi , Thanks much for the clue , i have completed the code now and its working as expected .